# Wordpress PHP navigation among pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a normal Corporate webpage hardcoding with Bootstrap, but I am creating it within Wordpress core, because we want to have a News section and some person so admin the posts.

So I created the Index.php, with all the content:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

  <div> Some body content</div>

<?php get_footer();?>
```

It works flawless. I did it following some tutorials.

The thing I want to do now is navigate among different sections.

If I use to have in normal bootstrap Index, About-us, Products, Contact-us... and I can access them with

```
 <a href="pages/about.php">Button</a>
```

How can I make it in Wordpress using PHP sentences?

I think in WP I must work differently, with single.php, not as easy as native HTML code.

Any links of help would be appreciated also, as I don't find clear tutorials for developers, just WP end users.
THANKS you all!

Answer (score 0):

Hi you mean menu for your site you can create a menu which you can put in your header, footer or anywhere you want. for this you have to register menu first

```
//register theme menu 
register_nav_menus( array( 
    'top menu' => 'Top Navigation',
));

//customize top header menu 
function ht_top_wp_nav() {
    wp_nav_menu( 
        array(
            'theme_location' => 'top menu',
            'container' => 'div',
            'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
            'container_id' => 'navbarResponsive',
            'items_wrap' => '<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">%3$s</ul>', 
            'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu',
            'menu'   => 'nav',
        )
    );
}
```

now after add this code in your theme functions.php there is a option available under your dashboard > appearance > menu when you create new menu you see a option to select which menu and there is a option to select Top Navigation.

now after that you can show it in frontend with this code

```
    if (has_nav_menu('top menu')) {
        {
            ht_top_wp_nav(); 
        }
    }
```

Hope it solve your issue

Comment: So what if in the Body, not in the navbar, I want to put links, buttons or images with <a> tags? Like, Want to know more About us?? and Link to About us.  How can I refer to another page? (eg. about-us.php)

Comment: you can add it anywhere you want

Comment: My main question was, I cannot add it as in normal HTML. `<a href="pages/about.php">Button</a>` It does not work. How can I link to other pages, in order to navigate among different pages? Thanks for your quick reply! =)

Comment: you can add custom link from dashboard > appearance > menu for Top Navigation and then when you add this inside ht_top_wp_nav(); your page.php it will appear in all pages.

Comment: I'm not working with TopNav yet, I just want to put clickable images that can take you to another page within my website. I left the TopNavbar for later, but with your help I will start now =) And look for linked-images later researching more. Many thanks for throwing some light! =)

Comment: <?php the_content(); ?> you can add this in body where you want to show content in page.php and add content from dashboard > pages > add